# GoDaddy Lost My DNS Settings: What to do?

Tags: dns, web-hosting

My MX records point to Google Apps and my mail was working perfectly for 2 years or more. Then the other day it stopped working. I managed to figure out that it was a DNS problem and reset my MX records, but it's a bit spooky that this happened. The MX records were deleted and replaced by the defaults.

Should I be worry that my Godaddy account was hacked? Complain to someone?

**Edit:** For discussion-o-GoDaddy purposes, DNS was reset on the 27th, 28th or 29th of September.

Comment: When did this happen? As the exact same thing happened to me recently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Total DNS Control" service has an option to actually import or export your entire zone into a plain text file. Actually, this is something you should do every time you make a change in your zone. As well, if you have multiple changes to do, or changes that will be the same across multiple zones, this is perhaps the easiest way to do it, if you're familiar with such text files.

I have a backup of all my zone files, so if any of them goes bezerk, I can restore it in a matter of minutes, given the TTL settings for both the zone and individual entries, of course.

Answer (score 4):

I would change my password just to be safe, but I think it might be a GoDaddy glitch, since the [same thing happened to Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/new-dns-provider/) with Stack Overflow’s DNS settings before they switched away from GoDaddy:

> Our domain name registrar is GoDaddy. We’ve had a lot of problems with GoDaddy’s handling of DNS, where DNS entries will suddenly appear and disappear at random. Often, changing a completely unrelated DNS record would result in other DNS entries going missing for hours. Extremely frustrating.

[That article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/new-dns-provider/) mentions a few alternatives for DNS providers, in case you feel like switching. Personally, I’ve been using [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/) lately and I’m satisfied with the service so far.

Comment: Fascinating. Unfortunately, GoDaddy has all of my hosting and DNS. Might be a hassle to change, no?

Comment: Yeah, the hosting would be a problem (I think.) Otherwise it would be a simple matter of pointing your domain to DynDNS's nameservers and recreating your MX, CNAMEs, etc. (which you would have to do anyway since GoDaddy deleted them.) You wouldn't even need to transfer the domain to DynDNS, you could keep it at GoDaddy if you'd like. I did that yesterday and it only took me a few minutes to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you have a strong password and your email account is secure, it's unlikely that your account was hacked. I'd still call GoDaddy and discuss it with them.

Personally, I always thought the GDCP UI was terrible. I use the freemium [ZoneEdit](http://zoneedit.com/) service, which is gratis if you only have one zone. You can just delegate your DNS to ZE from the GDCP, and you don't have to go back to GD ever.

Comment: What does "only have one zone" mean? I have many domain names (well, a handful).

Comment: They mean only one TLD.

Comment: cool, thanks for that. GoDaddy's UIs are terrible for everything, but in general they work quite well. But yeah, maybe I'll shop for a new service for DNS.

Comment: @Yar:  A "zone" is, essentially, and internet domain name (at least for your purposes at this time).